# Norms in the dual and bidual of $C(X,E)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $E$ be a Banach space, and consider the Banach space $C(X,E)$ with the sup norm with respect to the norm in $E$. We denote the dual of a Banach space $A$ by $A'$. It is known that the dual of $C(X,E)$ is the set of $E'$- valued regular Borel measures on $X$ with the total variation norm given by

$\|F\|=\text{sup}\{\sum_{i}\|F(X_{i})\|:\{X_{i}\} \text{ partition of }X\}$.

Fix $x\in X$ and consider the map $P:C(X,E)'\rightarrow C(X,E)'$ given by

$P(F)=F\restriction{\{x\}}=\delta(x)\otimes F(\{x\})$, i.e.

$P(F)f=F(\{x\})f(x)$.

Then $P$ is a norm-one projection on $C(X,E)'$.

The following are to be shown:

1. $\|F\|=\|F\restriction{\{x\}}\|+\|F-F\restriction{\{x\}}\| \, \forall F\in C(X,E)'$ and
2. $\|\Lambda\|=\text{max }\{\|P^{*}(\Lambda)\|, \|\Lambda-P^{*}(\Lambda)\|\} \, \forall \Lambda\in C(X,E)''$.

I'd be grateful for a hint on how to show this.

Does the first equality follow simply because the total variation is a measure?

In the second equality, it is clear that $\|P^{*}(\Lambda)\|\leq \|\Lambda\|$ and $\|\Lambda-P^{*}(\Lambda)\|\leq \|\Lambda\|$, but how do we show that $\|\Lambda\|$ is in fact the maximum of the two?

Thanks in advance.